# Access to "global" var in ActionScript 3.0 - AIR application

Tags: class, object, air, package

In a AIR Mobile application I have this code:

```
import character.*;

var player_1 = new characterObject("Player 1");
var player_2 = new characterObject("Player 2");
```

In the package class:

```
package character {

    public class characterObject extends MovieClip {
    public var characterName: Number;
    public var playerCounter: Number = 0;

        public function characterObject(myName: String) {
            characterName = myName;
            playerCounter++;
        }

    }
```

Can I access to *player_1.playerCounter* property inside player_2 object istance?
I need to increes the value of players only if *total_player* (a var that I want create as sum of *player_1.playerCounter* + *player_2.playerCounter* + *player_n.playerCounter* ...) is < of *x*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad idea.

Yo can try next thing

```
package character {
   public class CharactersModel extends Object{
      private var _chars : Array = [];
      public function addCharacter(char : characterObject) {
         _chars.push(char);
      }

      public function getChars() : Array {
          return _chars;
      }

      public function getCharByName(name : String ) : characterObject {
      //select from array and return
      //use it instead of null
      return null;
      }
   }
}
```

and update characterObject like this

```
private var _model : CharactersModel;
 public function characterObject(model : CharactersModel ,myName: String) {
    _model = model;            
    characterName = myName;
    playerCounter++;
    model.addCharacter(this);
  }

  public function getOtherChar(name : String) {
    return _model.getCharByName(name);
  }
```

and finally

```
import character.*;
var model : CharactersModel = new CharactersModel();
var player_1 = new characterObject(model ,"Player 1");
var player_2 = new characterObject(model ,"Player 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a vector to hold character instances outside of the characterObject class. Then you could refer to the length of the vector for the current amount.

```
var characters:Vector.<characterObject> = new Vector.<characterObject>();

characters.push( new characterObject("Player 1") );
characters.push( new characterObject("Player 2") );

trace( characters.length ); // 2
```

Comment: Ok, but can I access to vector inside of characterObject? Because I need to change the state of button (ADD / REMOVE characters) inside of it when the total amount of players is equal to a number.

Comment: I think it would be better if the manager or holder of characters kept an eye on how many there were. Then you could update the state of each one as you need (perhaps a public method on character that accepts a number when one is added or removed that you loop through and call on each one).